Golang. Хранение паролей для доступа к базе данных безопасно
Собираюсь написать свой первый веб-сервис на Go. Встал вопрос безопасного хранения пароля к базе данных.
Если следовать этому гайду, то нужно сделать переменную окружения.
Есть ли более безопасный способ хранения пароля к базе данных, чем переменная окружения применительно к веб-сервису написанному на Golang?

Ну для начала логичный вопрос — от чего конкретно вы хотите защититься-то? / «приложение можно отреверсить» — разумеется, приложение само по себе в принципе не должно содержать никаких доступов

@andreymal я хочу хранить пароль к базе данных максимально безопасно, без фанатизма, конечно. Хранить пароль в переменной окружения системы мне не кажется безопасным. Скажем, если взять хранение паролей для доступа java сервера WildFly к базе, то там создаётся java keystore, как один из способов. Keystore подключается к подсистеме elytron. Генерируется ключ и кладётся в keystore. Ключом затем шифруется пароль к базе данных и на выход выдаётся выражение типа "${klajwelkjawnmsadhja}", которое без ключа ничего не значит. Вот я и решил узнать, неужто для Golang нет более надёжного способа.

Почему переменная окружения это не безопасно?

@andreymal потому что хранится в незашифрованном виде и получить её значение если компьютер скомпроментирован можно просто. Вы про хранение паролей для Golang веб-сервиса что-то знаете или просто тратите моё время?

Если компьютер скомпрометирован, то вас не спасёт уже ничего. Если у приложения будет способ прочитать пароль, то и злоумышленник, скомпрометировавший компьютер, прочитает тот же самый пароль тем же самым способом. Так что в данном случае вы просто тратите своё время на невозможное

@andreymal очень смешно. Наверное AWS Key Management Service совершил невозможное.

Тогда я позадаю наводящие вопросы — каким образом по-вашему AWS KMS защищает от скомпрометированного компьютера?

@andreymal никак. Но всё же вернемся к исходному вопросу. Попробую его максимально упростить. Вы знаете более безопасные способы хранения пароля, чем в открытом виде в переменной окружения? Вынужден предупредить в виду своей крайней ограниченности я не способен поверить, что таких способов нет.

Скомпрометированный компьютер защитить невозможно, вот вы уже сами написали «никак» ¯\(ツ)/¯ А исходный вопрос должен содержать уточнение — от чего конкретно вы хотите защититься-то (и если от скомпрометированного компьютера, то вы уже сами написали что никак)

@andreymal Вы абсолютно правы, вдруг остальные не поймут. Переписал вопрос.

А по сути ничего не поменялось: фраза «более безопасный» подразумевает, что переменные окружения вы почему-то считаете небезопасными, что приводит к вопросу — почему, что в свою очередь опять приводит к вопросу — от чего конкретно вы хотите защититься-то

Вообще, касательно переменных окружения — пароль открытым текстом считается достаточно безопасным, если у посторонних не будет способа его прочитать. Для чтения тех же переменных окружения злоумышленнику придётся или получать доступ к пользователю, от имени которого запущен процесс с интересующими его переменными, или получать права администратора — то есть так или иначе скомпрометировать компьютер. И пока компьютер достаточно хорошо защищён от вмешательства посторонних, с переменными окружения всё будет хорошо (аналогичные рассуждения применимы и к файлам с паролями например)

Интересные обсуждения по теме на других ресурсах:

Reddit - Best practices for storing API keys and passwords securely in Golang?
Reddit - passwords, secrets, keys - best practice
Stackoverflow - Is it secure to store passwords as environment variables

Почему стоит хранить в формате переменных окружения
Есть довольно интересная методология от разработчиков облачной платформы Heroku, под
названием Twelve-Factor App.
Лучшие практики относительно хранения паролей, ключей API описаны здесь, раздел config.
Так же есть два перевода на хабре выжимка
и полный.
Конфигурация — это все параметры, которые меняются в зависимости от того где запущено приложение: логины, пароли, адреса
баз данных, ключи api и т.д.
Код не зависит от окружения, а конфигурация зависит. Поэтому код должен храниться в репозитории, а конфигурация в
окружении. Если вы можете опубликовать свой код в открытый доступ без компрометации персональных учетных записей – вы
все делаете правильно.
Понятие конфигурации не включает в себя внутренние конфигурации приложения, которые одинаковы для всех сред
развертывания.
Такие конфигурации скорее относятся к самому приложению и их лучше содержать в коде.
Не рекомендуется держать параметры конфигурации в конфигурационных файлах, так как можно по ошибке сохранить файл в
системе контроля версий.
Так же такой формат хранения может приводить к тому, что конфигурационные файлы будут разного формата и хранится в
разных местах.
Приложение двенадцати факторов хранит конфигурацию в переменных окружения (часто сокращается до env vars или env).
Переменные окружения легко изменить между развертываниями, не изменяя код. В отличие от файлов конфигурации, менее
вероятно случайно сохранить их в репозиторий кода. Так же в отличие от пользовательских конфигурационных файлов или других
механизмов конфигурации, таких как Java System Properties, они являются независимыми от языка и операционной системы
стандартом.
В приложении двенадцати факторов переменные окружения являются не связанными между собой. Каждая переменная окружения
полностью независима от других. Они никогда не группируются вместе в “окружения”, а вместо этого управляются независимо
для каждого развертывания.
Защищённость переменной окружения.
Незашифрованный пароль сохраненный где-нибудь это уже небезопасно.
Защита переменной окружения базируется исключительно на защите предоставляемой операционной системой.
Если система будет скомпроментирована, то не составит труда получить доступ к переменной окружения.
Т.е. в этом случае необходимо концентрироваться на защите самой машины, на которой выполняется код.
Основное же преимущество от использования переменной окружения, это то что значение переменной окружения не может
попасть в систему контроля версий.
Библиотеки Golang для шифрования/хранения секретов
Для шифрования/хранения секретных можно использовать следующие библиотеки:

keyring - работает с хранилищами учётных данных встроенных в систему, такими
как Windows Credential Manager, KWallet и другие. Но при компрометации системы это опять же не особо поможет.
sops - библиотека для работы с Mozilla Sops. Позволяет шифровать/дешифровать
данные. В данном случае основная проблема это хранение приватного ключа. Он не должен храниться на машине где запущено
приложение, иначе возвращаемся к утечке учётных данных. Соответственно необходима реализация стороннего провайдера для
дешифровки в момент, когда это нужно на другой машине. Но для моих целей это уже будет излишнее усложнение.

Поэтому как и предполагал буду хранить переменные окружения в CD/CI GitLab.
Буду рад, если кто-нибудь более компетентный напишет другой ответ.
